# Why adding fan to dry cabinet not improve dry performance?

Tags: humidity, condensation, fan

My dry cabinet is basically rubber sealed cabinet with peltier module to condense moisture and drain it out. The drying  process run quit slow from ambient humidity around 50% to 70% it take about 3 hour to decrease to 20% which I turn the knob to maximum power (the power Controlled by voltage regulator). So I decide to add fan in front of peltier module as shown. I thing more air flow will help more moiser to condense and faster the drying process but the result is wrost. the relative humidity stick around 35% I left it a night and still 35%
Any ideas what happen and how to improve the performance?
Note: I cut the fan wire befor take this picture
Note: The black plate behide is big heatsink that a quit warm
My theory:

1. Air flow from fane make the water that one condense to vaporize
2. Airflow make peltier temperature rise and moisture not condense anymore from 35%
3. Maybeif I can add more power to peltier It can catch moiser better.
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

Do I understand correctly that the fan is *inside* a sealed box, and the Peltier device is mounted in the wall of the box?  If so, then...

> Airflow make peltier temperature rise and moisture not condense anymore from 35%

...That sounds about right. It sounds like the purpose of the Peltier device is to create a *localized* cold spot where the water can condense.  When you switch on the fan, you're suddenly trying to chill the entire box. The Peltier device probably isn't able to move enough heat to do that.